# WiX - suppress Install and Close Buttons

Tags: visual-studio-2008, wix, wix3.6, bootstrapper, burn

I have a wix installation that currently uses the standard bootstrapper to bundle a number of MSI's together.

With the goal of automatically updating the applications, what I want is for the dialog to have the Install and Close buttons suppressed so that the install automatically starts with no user intervention.

I'm currently using the following Bootstrapper definition to suppress options button and License, but can I do what I want using one of the standard bootstrappers am I looking at having to create my own GUI?

```
<BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.HyperlinkLicense">
  <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication SuppressOptionsUI="yes" LicenseUrl="" LogoFile="logo.png" />
</BootstrapperApplicationRef>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WixStandardBootstrapperApplication does not support that: If it's started in "full UI," it will require the user to initiate the install. You can run the bootstrapper with the /passive switch to get the behavior you want.

Comment: Hi Bob many thanks for your answer - it did the trick.

It would seem that in passive mode it also ignores my LaunchTarget to kick off an application automatically, which is to be expected I guess. No rest for the wicked..